# Single Subquery returns multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

```
select distinct a.person.name, b.title,b.director.name 
  from movie_roles a, movie b
 where a.person.name=
 ( select b.director.name 
     from movie b, movie_roles a
    where b.director.name=a.person.name)
  and b.movieID=a.movie.movieID;
```

I keep getting error that saying single single subquery returns multiple rows in Oracle.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Time to learn about joins I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's self explanatory.In the following line

```
where a.person.name= ( select b.director.name from movie b, movie_roles a where b.director.name=a.person.name)
```

you get more than one result so you cannot use "=". Try

```
where a.person.name IN( select b.director.name from movie b, movie_roles a where b.director.name=a.person.name)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Just realized "=" will return a multiple row

Comment: Actually you subquery returns multiple results and this is the reason you cannot use '=' operator.